# get data from subclass after casting to superclass

Tags: java, casting, subclass, superclass

Hi guys I'm having this small problem. I have this:

```
public class Animal {
    //omitted
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
   private int speed;
}
```

Now that I have another class that generate an iterator and cast all of its object to the Animal one.

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
   Animal animal = (Animal) it.next();
}
```

However some of the objects are Dog and I dont know how to get the attribute "speed" from the subclass.

Sorry for asking this kind of question, I'm kind of new to Java. Thanks for concerning.

Comment: Check if the animal is an instance of Dog and cast it to Dog. However I believe that every animal has a speed ? You could set it to 0 in the base class and modify it if needed in the subclasses.

Comment: user2336315: Thank you, that is just an example :D not my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if animal is a `Dog`, then cast it

```
if (animal instanceof Dog) {
    ((Dog)animal).getSpeed();
}
```